# If $p^k-1$ divides $p^n-1$, then $\mathbb F_{p^k}\subset \mathbb F_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Suppose $p$ is a prime and $p^k-1$ divides $p^n-1$. How can I show that $\mathbb F_{p^k}\subset \mathbb F_{p^n}$? The only thing I can deduce from the given condition is that $\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times$ contains an element of order $p^k-1$ since $\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times$ is cyclic of order $p^n-1$, and any cyclic group $C_r$ contains an element of order $s$ provided $s$ divides $r$ (take $x^{r/s}$ where $x$ is a generator). How can I proceed?

Comment: Maybe you find your answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669679/the-degree-of-a-irreducible-polynomial-over-finite-field).

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is the set of roots of $x^{p^n}-x$.

Comment: Am I supposed to show that the powers of $\alpha$ (an element of the multiplicative group of order $p^k-1$) satisfy $x^{p^n-1}-1=0$? If I believe in the fact that $x^{p^k-1}-1$ divides $x^{p^n-1}-1$, then I can see that the $p^k-1$ powers of $\alpha$ satisfy it because they satisfy $x^{p^k-1}-1$. Also I know that the roots of $x^{p^r}-x$ in a field of characteristic $p $ form a subfield. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You can show by induction on $\max(k,n)$ that $\gcd(p^k-1, p^n-1) = p^{\gcd(k,n)}-1$. 
In particular, $p^k-1\mid p^n-1$ iff $k\mid n$. 
It is well-known that $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}\leq \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ iff $k\mid n$.